# Centering multiple divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

How can I center multiple (3) divs with images in it (all same size)?

Example:

[image: Example]

```css
.desc {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.desc_img {
  float: left;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container desc">
  <div class="desc_img">
    <i class="fa fa-link fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="desc_img">
    <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="desc_img">
    <i class="fa fa-share-alt fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, they're inline but I don't know how to center them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try CSS **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)**:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align items horizontally (in this case) */
  align-items: center;     /* align items vertically (in this case) */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.desc_img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container desc">
  <div class="desc_img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" height="50" width="50" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="desc_img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" height="50" width="50" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="desc_img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" height="50" width="50" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7zu6cmw/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pb2uq3y5/

Your problem is that the `<div>` elements do not assume a width when the CSS `float` property is not set to `clear`. If there are three elements that must be placed side by side, taking up the entire width of their parent, which, in this case, is the entire page width, then each one will have a width of 33.333...%. You must set the width in the CSS, because it is not assumed by the browser.

This will not work if a `.desc_img` element has a margin, padding, or border. There is a workaround for margin and padding, which is setting the `box-sizing` property to `padding-box` or `border-box`, which will resolve the issue with either padding or padding and border, respectively (there would be no reason to use `padding-box` only in your case, but some situations arise where it could be of use.) When margin is involved, you have two options (These options can also be used for resolving padding and border if necessary): flexbox (see @Michael_B's answer and add `width: 100%` to `.desc_img`'s CSS properties from his demo), and containing them each in a wrapper such that margins are set in `.desc_img` and widths are set in the containers of `.desc_img`.